# Python converting a string salesforce timestamp to date

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

This is the datetime string I am getting  2018-05-04T13:08:20.000+0000.
I want to convert it to a date 2018-05-04. Below is the for loop i want use but just can't seem to strip out all the hour secs and etc. Max_data is the string with 2018-05-04T13:08:20.000+0000

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = datetime.strptime(max_data,'%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = date.today()
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    print single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: So Do you no longer need the rest of the information?

Comment: All of this I don't need T13:08:20.000+0000. I just need Year month day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do in a one liner:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

max_data =  '2018-05-04T13:08:20.000+0000'
date = dt.strptime(max_data.split('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
print (date)
# output: datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 4, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp string you're having is an ISO8601 string. You can parse the information of this string using the `dateutil.parser` module as follows:

```
import dateutil.parser
Max_data = "2018-05-04T13:08:20.000+0000"
converted_data = dateutil.parser.parse(Max_data)
date_format_string = converted_data.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The result of `date_format_string` is `'2018-05-04'`

Answer (score 0):

Using the information you gave, I did the following with my version of your code(Just the parts that you need to have fixed)

```
Max_data =  '2018-05-04T13:08:20.000+0000' #How ever max data is assigned, this is not needed

print Max_data[:10] # This will only print the 2018-05-04 while removing everything else
```

The output: `2018-05-04`

Using `Max_data[:10]` is what it seems you are in need of(At least one method.
It isn't the same as the original code so you may not like this fix, though it is shorter then the original code.

Remove the `datetime.strptime(max_data,'%Y-%m-%d')` and replace it with`Max_data[:10]`

I know you don't need it exactly the way I placed it but its just to show how to get rid of the information you don't need

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the whole date string and then just use what you need, e.g.:

```
In []:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = datetime.strptime(max_data,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
end_date = datetime.now(start_date.tzinfo)
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    print(single_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

Out[]:
2018-05-04
2018-05-05
2018-05-06
2018-05-07
2018-05-08
2018-05-09
```

Note: you need to pass in the `tzinfo` to `now()` to get a tz aware datetime object (instead of using `date.today()`)

Note: in Py3.7 the standard library has added, `datetime.fromisoformat()`.

Comment: 'Note: in Py3.7 the standard library has added, datetime.fromisoformat().' The SF date doesn't follow this format.